# How can I control which function is being called, when using template

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 functions:

```
void func(void* Buf);
template<class T> void func(T& val);
```

I would like that a call with an array or some pointer to a type would go to the first call.
While calls with types like: int, double, long etc
would go to the second one, is that possible?

As it now, all calls go to the second one.

Answer (score 4):

> As it now, all calls go to the second one.

Except for a `void*`, of course. That's because, for every type besides `void*`, the template is a better match.

Change the first one to a template also.

```
template<class T> void func(T*);
```

That will be a better match for pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a specialized version of `func()` for `T` being `void*`:

```
template<> void func(void*& val) {
}
```

instead of providing an ambiguous overload.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you need is called partial template specialization. It works only for classes, so you need to turn your function into something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct funct_t
{
    static void exec(T &t)
    {
        std::cout << "T &" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct funct_t<T *> // specialization for pointer like types
{
    static void exec(T *t)
    {
        std::cout << "T *" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
void funct(T t)
{
    funct_t<T>::exec(t);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 0;
    int y[2];

    funct(x);
    funct(y);
    return 0;
}
```